# JSON data in Chart.js is splitting values

Tags: jquery, json, charts, chart.js

I am trying to draw a chart.js chart using a value returned with JSON. I've managed to make it read the values but it is splitting the numbers into separate data points.

My code is as follows:

```
function drawchart(){
var yaxisdata = yaxischartdata;
var labeldata = xaxischartdata;
var Data1 = {
labels : labeldata,
datasets : [{
    fillColor             : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
    strokeColor           : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointColor            : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointStrokeColor      : "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill    : "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke  : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data                  : yaxisdata
    }]
};
var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(Data1);
};
```

The chart renders, but the values seem to "split up". The json returned values here are "76" and "1200" but as you can see in the image below it is treating it as [7,6] and [1,2,0,0]

[image: chartjs numbers splitting]

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

I just tried adding the variables as arrays as per Victor's suggestion but it is now rendering like this:

[image]

Comment: Change `labels : labeldata` to this: `labels : [labeldata]`, similarly for `data : yaxisdata` , change it to this: `data: [yaxisdata]`, as labels and data take array as input in Chart.js. Hope this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data and labels must be an array. So your code will be something like:

```
function drawchart(){
  var yaxisdata = [yaxischartdata];
  var labeldata = [xaxischartdata];
  var Data1 = {
  labels : labeldata,
  datasets : [{
    fillColor             : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
    strokeColor           : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointColor            : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointStrokeColor      : "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill    : "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke  : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data                  : yaxisdata
    }]
  };
  var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
  var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(Data1);
};
```

Docs: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vcarvalho/qs2cnky4/

Comment: Thanks Victor, I just tried that and it is not showing the point. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Bruno, i just create [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcarvalho/qs2cnky4/) and looks like it's working. Can you please confirm the values of your data?

Comment: When i console.log the variables, I get this format: ["76"]